# How to increase size of mouse pointer for presentations?

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, accessibility

How to make the mouse pointer appear larger in size? Makes it easier to notice, and is handy during presentations or when working over darkly colored content.

I have done this in the past but forgot how. I vaguely recall it being an Accessibility feature, but cannot find any options in the System Preferences > Accessibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Cursor Size

[image]